# how to do a union or "or" in this case?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a main table that has the common information of two tables. Also I have two tables that has the particular information of each type. Finally I have a last table that has relation with any of this two secondary tables. It is posible that this last table has relation with one or both of this secondary tables.

The model is:

- MainTable(IDMainTable, Name...)
- Secondary01(IDSecondary01, IDMaintable, Name....)
- Secondary02(IDSecondary02, IDMainTable Name....)
- Data(IDData, Name...)
- DataRelationship(IDData, IDSecondary01, IDSecondary02)

I would like to get all the registers in the main table which any of the secondary tables has  relation with a data. I have the IDData as condition.

In SQL it would be something like that:

```
select * from Maintable, Secondary01, DataRelationship
where MainTable.IDMainTable = Secondary01.IDMainTable
and Secondary01.IDSecondary01 = DataRelationship.IDSecondary01
and DataRelationship.IDData = 1234

UNION
select * from Maintable, Secondary02, DataRelationship
where MainTable.IDMainTable = Secondary02.IDMainTable
and Secondary02.IDSecondary02 = DataRelationship.IDSecondary02
and DataRelationship.IDData = 1234
```

How can I do this query with extended methods or linq to entities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method.

> Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality
>   comparer.

Like:

```
var query = (from t in db.Maintable
            from r in db.Secondary02
            //.....your rest of query
            select ...)
            .Union
            (from t in db.Maintable
            from r in db.Secondary02
            //.....your rest of query
            select ...);
```

Comment: and  this way make one or two queries to the database? I would like to access once to the database.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, do not iterate the query, just form your query using `Union` and while iterating it should go to database once.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, just added a code snippet to depict what I meant.